# JAVA_HOME path required to be updated after each update of JDK/JRE

Tags: java, windows, java-home

In the windows environment variable the JAVA_HOME path needs to be updated after each time upgrading the JDK/JRE. Is there any solution for this to maintain the default path for JAVA_HOME irrespective of the version it gets upgraded?
Let me know if anyone has any solution for this.

we tried of setting the new path while installing the JRE, even this path changes after upgrading the JRE.

Comment: The short answer is "use a symbolic link".  See https://www.howtogeek.com/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/.

Answer (score 0):

By default, (Oracle) Java installers for Windows put the installation in directory whose name matches the Java version and patch number; e.g.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30
```

This allows you to have multiple different versions of Java installed.  That's a good thing because a lot of applications require a particular Java version.  And to that end, you probably want to use different Java versions for different applications.

However, if you want a default version that you can easily change without changing lots of classpath settings in lots of places, the obvious way to do it is to use a [symbolic link or symlink](https://www.howtogeek.com/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/).  For example:

C: Program Files:
Java:
jdk1.6.0_30:
...
jdk1.8.0_77:
...
default -> jdk1.8.0_77

Then your use `C:\Program Files\Java\default\bin` in `%PATH%` and `C:\Program Files\Java\default` in `%JAVA_HOME%`, and similarly change any `-cp` options in batch files, etc.

Once you have done all of that, you can switch to a different default Java version, by simply updating the target for the `default` symlink to a different installation directory.

Note that Linux has a more sophisticated way of doing this using the `alternative` utilities.  But under the hood that is all done with symlinks.